# Ставится ли точка после подписи к фотографиям, рисункам?

Tags: пунктуация, редактура, корректура

Если в книгу помещается картинка (изображение мозаики или храма), то надо после подписи к ней ставить точку? Можно ли об этом почитать у Розенталя или где-нибудь в справочнике издателя?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В конце подписи никаких знаков препинания ставить не принято. Структурные части подписи можно рекомендовать отделять друг от друга точкой, а между элементами одной структурной части (дата и место съемки или создания картины; техника и материал; название хранилища и его местонахождение) ставить запятую.
Если структурные части подписи выделяют в отдельные строки, точку после них не ставят.

**Рафаэль. Мадонна Конестабиле. Ок. 1504. Эрмитаж, Санкт-Петербург**

```
                                Деревня  
                  Картина Ф. А. Васильева. Масло. 1869  
                      Русский музей, Санкт-Петербург
```

**Христос и Богоматерь на троне. Мозаика купола церкви Санта Мария ин Трастевере в Риме. XII век**

[**Подписи к иллюстрациям**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dv-mC8T4fasC&pg=PT488&lpg=PT488&dq=%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=X1ZEvjWWBR&sig=CHgiGXbkCMbx-6zl_mUeab0I3zo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjomr2axtraAhXB0qQKHavVAFcQ6AEwAXoECAAQLQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

В "Справочной книге корректора и редактора" А.Мильчина, в разделе "Подписи к иллюстрациям" сказано следующее:

> 17. В самом конце подписи точки не ставят, за исключением случаев, когда подпись представляет собой цитату из иллюстрируемого
>       художественного произведения (законченную фразу-цитату завершают
>       точкой).

Comment: Т.е. точка ставится после закрывающей кавычки? А если цитата представляет собой вопрос?

Comment: @Юлия Я не могу уверенно ответить на Ваш вопрос. Не помню, чтобы мне встречалось такое правило или примеры в реальных книгах. Аргументы можно придумать и за и против. (Своё мнение оставлю при себе, поскольку я не профессионал :)