# «Начальник завода – Иван Иванов». Нужно ли тире?

Tags: тире

«Начальник завода – Иван Иванов». (пример подписи к фото). Нужно ли тире?

Answer (score 1):

1. Если это подпись под фотографией, то точка в самом конце не ставится.
   ([Ставится ли точка после подписи к фотографиям, рисункам?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440390/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC))
2. Сам текст оформляется без тире.

   ```
                Директор "Уралмашзавода" Николай Иванович Рыжков (1970 — 1971)  

   Генеральный директор ПО "Уралмаш" Николай Иванович Рыжков (1971 — 1975)
   ```
3. Расположение подписи посередине — дело автора. Если текст под фотографией объемный, то он обычно не центруется.
   [Музей истории](https://www.kommersant.ru/gallery/3410359#id=1483778)

Answer (score 0):

Профессия, должность, звание, сан и пр. не отделяются знаком препинания от имени. Отделение (тире, двоеточие, флеш и др.) применяется в титрах игровых фильмов.

Answer (score 0):

Если это подпись под фотографией, то это не предложение, а словосочетание. Тире не ставится.

Но если это предложение, то тире нужно ставить, это будет тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. (Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится, если оба главных члена выражены существительными в именительном падеже.)
Например, вы описываете завод. *Уралмаш — машиностроительное предприятие в городе Екатеринбурге. Генеральный директор завода — Смолин Сергей Юрьевич.*

Примечание. Словосочетание "начальник завода" устарело. В наше время употребляется словосочетание "руководитель завода" или конкретное указание должности (директор завода, генеральный директор завода и т. п.).